# How to send to back or move to front

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This question was already asked in here but none of the answers have solved my problem. I have picture A, I copied and pasted picture B and it's covering picture A now. How do I move picture B to the back? Where is the option "send to back" or "move to front?" I've used it before and I know it's there but I can't find it anymore. I'm using CS5

Comment: If this question has been asked before, can you please [edit] your question to include a link to the previous version?

Answer (score 1):

Bring Forward – Ctrl + ]
Send Backward – Ctrl + [

Go to Layer -> Arrange -> Bring to front and several options

Or with the mouse u can just click the layer and drag up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Send to Back - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>

Move to Front - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>

Hope this will work

Comment: Welcome! Can you add some screenshots showing that the given short keys solves the problem? As it stands now this is more an comment ...